# XML - Find a node by name with an attribute with a certain value

Tags: xml, xpath

Given the following XML, using Powershell

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="StiTilAdbFiler" value="c:\work\myfolder" />
    <add key="notthisne" value="c:\work\myfolder" />
   </appSettings>
 </configuration>
```

Using the follwoing Xpath

```
//*[name()='add']
```

I will get the result

```
Element='<add key="StiTilAdbFiler" value="c:\work\myfolder"/>'
Element='<add key="notthisne" value="c:\work\myfolder"/>'
```

But - I would like to find only the one with attribute key=StiTilAdbFiler, what would be the xpath for that?

Answer (score 1):

While preparing to post my question - I had to verify that the question was as clearly stated as possible, and then, thanks to https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html I did answer my own question

```
//add[@key='StiTilAdbFiler']
```